# Axis: Too many parameters, parameter is exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, automation, axis

Using axis plugin of eclipse, have generated client stub from a SOA service. In one of the generated classes, eclipse shows following error

*Too many parameters, parameter is exceeding the limit of 255 words eligible for method parameters*

Taking at a closer look, it seems we are violating the [Java VM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se6/html/ClassFile.doc.html#74353) (section 4.3.3) which says - the number of method parameters is limited to 255 by the definition of a method descriptor, where the limit includes one unit for this in the case of instance or interface method invocations.

Seems to be an limitation of axix and there exists an unresolved bug with axis (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2823)

Now, the question is - do we have any other ways to overcome this error ?? (apart from modifying generated stub)

Comment: It sounds like you should use some array of objects instead of direct method parameters. Axis does not recognize this correctly, and manual intervention is required (ie: Code by hand). On the other hand: It does not sound as a really well designed SOA: The number of parameters even when parsing an array seems to be on the high side.

Comment: Yep, agree that SOA is not greatly designed. You wont believe, that particular method had 400+ parameters.. But, wanted know of any way apart from manual intervention of code. Seems the answer is no.

Comment: This might work (really horrible hack): Build an intermediate service splitting the request string in 2 parts, and generated the axis code against that (I estimate that will be less work than really implementing an array of objects for those numbers yourself).